# pip install throws a "Command erroed out with status 1"

Tags: python, pip, mysql-python

I tried to install mysql module and got this:

```
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1
```

Then I tried this
install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient

but got "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for mysqlclient "

[This is the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThUIt.png)

[log, part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9bvm.png)

[log, part3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5N9e.png)

Comment: Installed Visual studio tools and got this:

MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo inclui
r: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory

Comment: May be you could find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062920/pip-install-mysqlclient-error

Comment: I tried all answers from that post @SMVaidhyanathan

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? If you are using 3.7.x , then uninstall that and install Python 3.6.5 and type the command ```pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12```

Comment: I installed this on my personal computer and a server without a problem, but now it doesnt work in another server with the same specs as the previous server

Comment: pip install mysql-connector after I installed visual studio build tools worked!

Answer (score 0):

May be mysql connector is missing
try installing mysql connector

```
pip3 install mysql-connector --user
```